# Why these two C functions generate different return values when called in Python using ctypes lib?

Tags: python, c

Here I have implemented two C functions:

```c
void testFunc1(int **a)
{
    int temp[4] = {1,2,3,4};
    *a = temp;
}

void testFunc2(int **a, int b)
{
    int temp[4] = {1,2,3,4};
    *a = temp;
}
```

As shown, these two functions should change the value of *a to the address of temp[0], thus the array temp could be returned via the pointer a. b is not a used parameter, I put it in testFunc2 because I found it may cause some confusing results. Then I compiled this code file into "./test.dll".

However when I called these two function in python via ctypes lib as this:

```py
from ctypes import *

testdll = CDLL("./test.dll")
testdll.testFunc1.argtypes = (POINTER(POINTER(c_int)),)
testdll.testFunc2.argtypes = (POINTER(POINTER(c_int)), c_int)

print("Test func 1:")
a = pointer(pointer(c_int(-1)))
print("  Before calling func:")
print(f"                      a={a}")
print(f"             a.contents={a.contents}")
print(f"    a.contents.contents={a.contents.contents}")
testdll.testFunc1(a)
print("  After calling func:")
print(f"                      a={a}")
print(f"             a.contents={a.contents}")
print(f"    a.contents.contents={a.contents.contents}")

print("Test func 2:")
a = pointer(pointer(c_int(-1)))
print("  Before calling func:")
print(f"                      a={a}")
print(f"             a.contents={a.contents}")
print(f"    a.contents.contents={a.contents.contents}")
testdll.testFunc2(a, c_int(4))
print("  After calling func:")
print(f"                      a={a}")
print(f"             a.contents={a.contents}")
print(f"    a.contents.contents={a.contents.contents}")
```

The print was like this:

```
Test func 1:
  Before calling func:
                      a=<__main__.LP_LP_c_long object at 0x00000263EC1B2CD0>
             a.contents=<__main__.LP_c_long object at 0x00000263EC1B2D50>
    a.contents.contents=c_long(-1)
  After calling func:
                      a=<__main__.LP_LP_c_long object at 0x00000263EC1B2CD0>
             a.contents=<__main__.LP_c_long object at 0x00000263EC1B2DD0>
    a.contents.contents=c_long(1)
Test func 2:
  Before calling func:
                      a=<__main__.LP_LP_c_long object at 0x00000263EC1B2E50>
             a.contents=<__main__.LP_c_long object at 0x00000263EC1B2CD0>
    a.contents.contents=c_long(-1)
  After calling func:
                      a=<__main__.LP_LP_c_long object at 0x00000263EC1B2E50>
             a.contents=<__main__.LP_c_long object at 0x00000263EC1B2BD0>
    a.contents.contents=c_long(0)
```

It shows that testFunc2 seems to make *a point to an integer whose value is "0". This is a confusing result because testFunc2 only adds an unused argument b in its arguments list. Why would it generate different result compared to testFunc1?

Please refer to the problem part. I have mentioned my experiment there.

Comment: "thus the array temp could be returned via the pointer a." --> No.  On return `*a` is not valid as `temp` is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both functions invoke undefined behaviour as you assign reference to the automatic storage duration arrays (and consequently dereference it in the Python code) which stop to exist when the function returns.

> Why these two C functions generate different return values when called
> in Python using ctypes lib?

Because it is an undefined behaviour and you cannot assume any behavior.

You need to make them static or allocate them dynamically:

```
void testFunc1(int **a)
{
    static int temp[4] = {1,2,3,4};
    *a = temp;
}

void testFunc1(int **a)
{
    int *temp = malloc(4 * sizeof(*temp));
    memcpy(temp, (int[]){1,2,3,4}, 4 * sizeof(*temp));
    *a = temp;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are having fun with `memcpy(temp, (int[]){1,2,3,4}, 4 * sizeof(*temp));`.

Comment: Much appreciate! Can't believe I forgot this entire thing. I suppose I must be writing too much Python and too little C these days.